# Shortcuts in php storm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I don't know if this is the right place for this question but I must ask,

In visual studion ide the shortcut [Ctrl -] and [Ctrl +] navigate you inside your opened document according to the last lines you've been on.

Is there a matching shortcut for php storm?

for example :

I open a php file go to line 100 than 4569 than press Ctrl - and get back to 100 than Ctrl + and get back to 4569.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Navigate` | **Back** / **Forward** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>).

Comment: @RobinWinslow, disable/change system shortcuts (most likely your video driver provides them), or change them in the IDE `Settings` | `Keymap`.

Comment: Right you are. Common problem: http://superuser.com/questions/373832/disable-alt-arrow-display-flip. In my case it was my Intel Graphics options.

Comment: Thank you @CrazyCoder

Please, update for Mac OS
Navigate back/forward: cmd + alt + left / cmd + alt + right